# `while` or `for` loop with $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know if it's possible to use `while` or `for` with a nested call to `$http.get`:

This is an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.comments.length; i++) {
   alert($scope.comments[i].id); // = 2
   $http.get('/api/logged/like/isliked?id=' + $scope.comments[i].id).success(function(data, status, header, config) {
        alert('Test');
        alert($scope.comments[i].id); // Not executed.
   }).error(function(data){alert('The requeste isn't working');}); }
```

I put two `alert`s to display the id of my comment I'm using to retrieve JSON. I get the id with the first alert, then 'Test' for the second, but the third alert isn't displaying. Why not?

Here an example of the JSON:

```
{data":[
   {"id":2,"is_liked":false,"nb_comments":1,"nb_likes":1,
    "date_creation":"2014-05-26T17:03:54+0000"},
   {"id":1,"is_liked":true,"nb_comments":0,"nb_likes":1,
    "date_creation":"2014-05-26T17:00:26+0000"}
]}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's such a good idea to do an HTTP request for every single comment...?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**The problem:**

[Don't make functions inside of a loop](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop) ...

Each call of your function is actually referencing the same copy of `i` in memory. A new closure is created each time the for loop runs, but each one captures the same environment. Therefore, every call to `$http.get` (an asynchronous function) results in the firing of a callback referencing the same *final* value of `i` from the end of loop.

**A solution:**

Pass `i` as a parameter to a separately defined function:

```
var getIsLiked = function(i){
  $http.get('isliked.json' + $scope.comments[i].id)
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log('Test');
      console.log('i is ', i);
      console.log($scope.comments[i].id);
  }).error(function(data){console.log("The request isn't working");}); }
}

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.comments.length; i++) {
  getIsLiked(i);
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjzHfFjYlpmNsFMWi1W7?p=preview)

This can be really hard to wrap your head around, but it's worth the time to understand deeply. Not only will it help you to avoid similar problems in the future, it will also give you a better understanding of closures, an important concept in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried what you advice and that works thanks a lot @MarcKline

Answer (score -1):

The third alert is inside the `error` callback of your `$http.get` promise. It will only be executed if the request fail. The two first alert will be executed if the request pass OR the third one will be launched if it fails.

Comment: there are 2 alerts on success one outside and one on error

Comment: Ok, I don't see why this alert is not called. Could you provide a example of your bug with a service like [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/). It will help me fix your bug.

Comment: Thx for your help but @Dawson find the solution

Comment: As noted, that answer *does not* solve your problem.