# Given Instagram comment id, how to retrieve its original media id? Passing count into http.call?

Tags: http, instagram-api

**Question 1:**

I have only Instagram comment-id, is it possible to retrieve its original media-id?

**Question 2:**

Using instagram media-id, through http.call (GET), collecting comments of the specific media-id

Let's say the **totalMediaCount** is **33**.

```
for(i=0; i<totalMediaCount; i++) {
    HTTP.call('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + media-id[i] + '/comments?access_token=' + instagramAccessToken, {}, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {    
            //console.log(response);
            console.log(i);
    });
}
```

The result is:

```
33

33

33

33 ...

33

33
```

Which I expect to have the result like this:

```
0

1

2

3

4

5

...

30

31

32
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. cannot get `media_id` from a `comment_id`, no APIs for it
2. `HTTP.call` is asynchronous, so the `for` is loop is complete by the time the first HTTP.call is executed.

try this:

```
for(i=0; i<totalMediaCount; i++) {
    var index = i;
    HTTP.call('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + media-id[index] + '/comments?access_token=' + instagramAccessToken, {}, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {    
            //console.log(response);
            console.log(index);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Noted on #1 but still no luck for #2. It still show 33, 33, ...., 33 instead of 0, 1, 2, ..., 32, 33

Comment: I think the working solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922301/while-or-for-loop-with-http-get