# Looping $http.get requests in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I'm playing with Marvel API as I'm building a character showcase however Marvel limits the amount of results you can retrieve in a single get request to 100.

I've tried to put it inside the for loop but it isn't working. I have tried to implement a method suggested as a solution [`while` or `for` loop with `$http.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922301/while-or-for-loop-with-http-get)

My code:

```
var loopRequests = function(i){
      $scope.offsetParam = 0;
      $http.get($scope.baseUrl, {
        params: {
          offset: $scope.offsetParam,
          limit: 100,
          ts: $scope.timeStamp,
          apikey: $scope.publicKey,
          hash: $scope.hash
        }}).then(function(response){

        $scope.characters = response.data.data.results;

      });
}

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  loopRequests(i);
  $scope.offsetParam += 100;
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- Request 1: Offset 0, Limit 100
- Request 2: Offset 100, Limit 100
- Request 3: Offset 200, Limit 100
- Request 4: Offset 300, Limit 100 etc...

Any help with this will be appreciated.

//Edit: It needs to wait for the last request to finish

Comment: Do you have to wait for the last request to finish?

Comment: @zero298 Edit. Yes, it has to finish loading the first 100 before loading next 100

Comment: You should add that in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). The `loopRequests` function creates a closure with `$scope.offsetParam`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass in the offset param, otherwise it will be overwritten by your for loop.

You can use $q.all() to wait for a list of promises:

```
var loopRequests = function(offset){
    return $http.get($scope.baseUrl, {
        params: {
          offset: offset,
          limit: 100,
          ts: $scope.timeStamp,
          apikey: $scope.publicKey,
          hash: $scope.hash
        }});
}

var promises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    $scope.offsetParam += 100;
    promises.push(loopRequests($scope.offsetParam));
}

$q.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results))
```

Comment: the OP hasn't expressed that the requests need to be sequential - the example given is for parallel requests

Comment: true but its not hurting anyone :)

Comment: The `loopRequest` function has a parameter named `i` which is never used inside the function. The answer make two GET requests both of which return results to the same scope variable.

Comment: restructured answer to accommodate waiting for all promises to return